# Can a person use AI-generated human faces as their profile picture?

Tags: social-media, artificial-intelligence

I've read an article about marketers creating fake linkedin accounts with AI-generated human faces as pfp. A human face makes the account more professional and intimate.

I'm not talking about using AI to edit images or AI generated a famous person's face etc. This is where AI generate from scratch a face that looks like an ordinary human except that human/face doesn't exist.

And just in general, what about an AI face for Gmail, website bio picture, twitter, and social media in general where the account is used to do business with clients?

Comment: People use all manner of icons and avatars in social media and other web forums, many obviously non-human.  (*consider for example the one assigned to you here...*) what makes you think the method of creation would matter?

Comment: The headline question is "Can a person use" and the answer to that question is obviously "yes". I presume that the real question is, "Is it legal for a person to use" or better yet, "when is it legal for a person to use".

Comment: @ohwilleke, you have been around here long enough to know that that is the reading we always give to "Is it possible ..." type questions. You know, unless they are physically impossible.

Comment: Is this not more of an ethical / practicality question than actually anything to do with law?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the gist of the question is that by way of using a [real-like image of the face of a human being](https://generated.photos/face-generator) (as opposed to some traditional avatar/profile picture that is obviously not a photo of a face), the user makes an impression that the picture is their real photo when in fact it is not — in fact, the person on the picture does not even exist.

There is obviously nothing wrong with using such pictures per se (assuming no intellectual property is violated).

However, there *is* an angle at which it may be illegal, especially where the aim is to make "the account more professional and intimate".

Specifically, if using such photos is aimed to bolster trust where the user in fact aims to use that trust to **deceive** people, using such profile pictures effectively becomes part of the user's [modus operandi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_operandi).

For example, consider Rob who wants to swindle people of money on Upwork, or on a dating site. He creates an  account and attaches an AI-generated picture looking like a real photo of a real person. Employers on Upwork will rarely hire a person unless they see their face. Showing your face on a dating site is all the more so paramount. Rob knows that, and he doesn't want to post his real face because he doesn't want to be caught (or because he doesn't look attractive for potential dates). So, he deceives people by posting a fake face, and proceeds with the rest of his modus operandi. Such a use of AI-generated picture will of course be illegal.

Comment: How would you define deceive though? And what about "swindle" people of money on Upwork? If Rob uses an AI-generated face and gets hired, AND does the job on par with the requirements like any other worker, would that be illegal?

Comment: @NoName "Deceive" in this context means obtaining benefit or advantage which would not be obtainable if those who provide it knew that the image was not your real photo. In your example, if Rob's Upwork employer does not care how Rob looks like, then Rob does nothing wrong. However, if the employer says "I only hire slim-faced people with brown eyes and a high forehead" and Rob is a fat, round-faced, blue-eyed dude with a low forehead pretending not to be, that would be deceit.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

My profile picture, while it is not AI-generated, is not a picture of me. It's perfectly legal for me to use that picture or for you to use the computer-generated geometric pattern in pink that you are currently using. If and when you replace that picture, you can use an image of yourself, someone else, your cat, Mt Kilimanjaro, or an AI-generated image of a multi-tentacled alien monstrosity. These are all part of our right to freedom of expression.

Now, Stack Exchange is free to introduce and enforce rules on what profile pictures (among other things) are allowed or not because it's their site. If they want to ban AI-generated art in profile pictures, they can; but they haven't.